# how to keep UIScrollView in place when text field selected (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

when I select a UITextField the scroll view moves down and I want it to remain where it is

I have tried ScrollView.contentOffset.y = 0 and I dont Know what else to try

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can set the `isScrollEnabled` property to false.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled):

> If the value of this property is true, scrolling is enabled, and if it is false, scrolling is disabled. The default is true.